# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fails with privilege exception when table exists

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I discovered that `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` will fail with `insufficient_privilege` if the role executing the statement does, in fact, not have the necessary privileges, but does so regardless of whether the table exists or not.  I would expect that if the table exists, the statement succeeds without making any modifications.  Is that reasonable, or am I missing something?

The docs (for 9, 10, 11, and 12) all say simply

> `IF NOT EXISTS`
>
> Do not throw an error if a relation with the same name already exists. A notice is issued in this case. Note that there is no guarantee that the existing relation is anything like the one that would have been created.

I don't know whether a notice about the privilege check taking precedence over the existence check is appropriate here, but I feel like either it should be documented (maybe it is, somewhere else?), or that the behavior should change (could this be a backwards compatibility issue?).

I've worked around it by

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl();
    EXCEPTION WHEN insufficient_privilege THEN
        IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
            WHERE schemaname = current_schema() AND tablename = 'tbl'
        ) THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
     WHEN others THEN RAISE;
 END;
 $$;
```

but in the end, that query is not in code I own, so my ability to change it is limited, and if I can't get that change accepted, I believe I either have to get Postgres changed (which is admittedly likely a larger lift) or accept that I have to give the user more privilege than I want it to have.

Comment: Potentially interesting IMO, but I'm not seeing a practical problem. You have a user that shouldn't be able to create a table trying to create a table. Failing one way is as good as failing another, right? If you want the user to know if a table exists, you query the system catalog, right? Each has a distinct privilege requirement IIRC. Where's the conflict? 

(also: welcome to the network etc etc, good first question! :p)

Comment: FWIW - you can review the [one of the contribution FAQs](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Submitting_a_Patch) if you're interested in submitting an update to the docs (which should be easier than getting a patch approved to the core code)

Comment: I only care if the table exists, not whether I can create it, so I specifically don't want it to fail when it does exist. In fact, the table will exist, but I can't prevent the code that creates it from running. (And thanks for the kudos!)

Comment: I think it might be worth being a bit more specific about your implementation. You can always get "fancy" with psql, `\!` and `'echo "select..." | \gexec'` type operators (I sure do 0_0). Please feel free to join [chat] as well to rubber duck a bit in pursuit of a well defined post!

Comment: Have you take a look at the [System Access Functions(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE) `SELECT has_table_privilege('tbl', 'select');` this will throw an exception if the table does not exist, false if the table does exist and the user does not have the privilege

Comment: The result of [that chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53600542#53600542) was the hypothesis that in order to lock the schema for potential modification, the role executing `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` needs to be able to take a lock, which is a schema-modifying operation, thus a privilege failure before the existence check. I've sent a message to the `pgsql-bugs` mailing list for verification.